# Postprocess django template nodes to combine tags before rendering

Tags: python, django, templates

I have a requirement for consecutive custom template tags to be combined before rendering the template in django 1.6+.  The tags may be identical or different tags from a selected list of "compatible" tags.

I am trying to loop through the templates `nodelist` prior to `render(context)` being called.  This loop would combine consecutive nodes that are compatible, however I can't work out how to automatically call a function on the template before it is rendered with a context.

I have looked at

1) **middleware** - none seem to have access to the compiled template node list
2) **custom template class** - breaks shortcuts like `render` and `render_to_response`
3) **function called directly on template in the view** - same issue as above

Any thoughts on how this could be achieved?

---

*A bit of background*

The basic idea is to have different template tags "render together" e.g. in a simplified example:

```
{% tag_one "1A" "1B" %}{% tag_two "2A" %}
```

Instead of rendering as two separate blocks:

```
[ 1A 1B ][ 2A ]
```

This would render as a single tag block:

```
[ 1A 1B 2A ]
```

There is a bit more logic than this behind the tag's render function but not relevant here...

Comment: does my answer satisfy your request? there is anything I can do to improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use this snippet: [Capture template output as a variable](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/545/) and define a [new filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) that removes the "`][`" or whatever inside of it.

**example** (in a file in your `templatetags` directory):

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

register = template.Library()

@register.tag(name='captureas')
def do_captureas(parser, token):
    try:
        tag_name, args = token.contents.split(None, 1)
    except ValueError:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("'captureas' node requires a variable name.")
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endcaptureas',))
    parser.delete_first_token()
    return CaptureasNode(nodelist, args)

class CaptureasNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, nodelist, varname):
        self.nodelist = nodelist
        self.varname = varname

    def render(self, context):
        output = self.nodelist.render(context)
        context[self.varname] = output
        return ''


@register.filter(name='join_my_tags')
@stringfilter
def join_my_tags(text):
    return text.replace(' ][ ', '')
```

**usage** (in your view):

```
{% captureas my_tags %}{% tag_one "1A" "1B" %}{% tag_two "2A" %}{% endcaptureas %}
{{my_tags|join_my_tags}}
```

---

**untested, alternative approach**: it does not requires any templatetag but you have to be very selective in the replacement if you want to avoid collateral effects (e.g. messing up your javascript code). It is similar to your attempts but act after rendering, not before.

modify your view in this way:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    myresponse = render(request, 'index.html')  # add your context object if you need it
    return HttpResponse(myresponse.content.replace(' ][ ', '')) # you may eventually use regex or eventually even a full html parser (!) but please take performances in account :)
```

Comment: Thanks furins - a good functional answer.  I was hoping for something a bit lighter on the template tags - i.e. not requiring any additional markup.  I wonder if I can use the parser to "peek ahead"?

Comment: in this case you may parse and manipulate the HTTPResponse before returning it, but it seems to me that this approach will add additional work to your server

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide you the alternative approach in a more concrete form. I've not time to test it but it should be a simple replacement in your code so you may try it if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can "peek ahead" in the parser provided to the template tag.  For instance the following uses `parser.next_token()` to inspect the next few `TemplateNodes` to see if they are compatible.

```
def my_tag(parser, token):
    parse_me = [token]

    # the following lines check if there are any additional nodes
    # that we should combine and adds them to a list for processing 
    if parser.tokens:
        while parser.tokens[0].token_type == 2 and parser.tokens[0].content[0:3] == 'my_':
            parse_me.append(parser.next_token())

    contents = ""
    for tok in parse_me:
        # apply some logic to combine the nodes
        contents += tok.contents 

    return MyCustomNode(contents)
```